# How to verify a CRC in receiver terminal?

Tags: crc

I am studying some computer knowledge by myself. I find a puzzle when I study the CRC. Now I know how to calculate a CRC value of a message, but I wonder how to verify it in receiver terminal when the rules require REFIN.

I'd like to put an example.

The message I want to check is 00010011.
The polynomial is 10011.
Init: 0x00
Refin: True
Reout: True
Xorout: 0x00

After calculation, the CRC value is 0100.

So the actual message to be delivered is 000100110100.

After the receiver terminal receives the message, it needs to verify it. How does it do this? Maybe it has two ways. First, it can compute the CRC via binary division, and compare the calculated and received CRC values.
Second, it can directly append the CRC value to the data. The receiver then calculates using exact division.

But I find some questions here.

1. Probably because of Refin and Reout, I can not verify it directly using the exact division, it has remainder.
2. If I want to obey the same rules to verify the message + CRC, 000100110100, it only has 12 bits, not enough 2 byte, so I can't complete the REFIN. I tried to append zeros in MSB side and LSB side， but in the division process I still can not get all zeros remainder.

So, could you give me some direction?

How does the receiver terminal verify the CRC?

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE as defined by this site.

Comment: @Andyaka I am sorry I don't quite know which site is the most suitable for this topic.

Comment: Computer Science maybe? https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are over-thinking this. Receive message, which is payload+CRC. Compute your local CRC from the payload. Compare your CRC with the recevied CRC.

Comment: @GrahamNye No, for example CRC-16 has 16 bits of CRC data and can be calculated using 16-bit variable, even if the polynomial itself has 17 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work in bytes. You can operate in bits.

And yes there are two ways. Calculate CRC of message and check if calculated and received CRCs match. The other way is to keep feeding in the received CRC into calculations and the result should be zero. But depending on things it can also be some other but constant value for correctly reveived message.

The algorithm is the same for each bit but depending on the reflect being true or false you rearrange your shift register direction and mirror the polynomial in any way necessary to end up with correct calculations.

So that's why it's easier to think one bit at a time, because for bytes of 8 bits, you always have to think if it is the least or most significant bit that must be processed first.